# How to change my T-SQL query to overwrite a csv file rather than append data to it?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, csv, openrowset

I have the following T-SQL codes configured to run on a daily basis using SQL Server Agent job. My database is running on SQL Server 2012.

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=C:\;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited','SELECT * FROM [myfile.csv]')

SELECT ReservationStayID,NameTitle,FirstName,LastName,ArrivalDate,DepartureDate FROM [GuestNameInfo]
```

My issue is that the output of this query is being appended to the existing records in the `csv` file. I want the output to overwrite the existing content each time the SQL Server Agent job is run.

How do I modify my query to acheive this?

Comment: If you use `BCP`, it will create the file for you each time and you can add the date stamp to the file name as @Jen R has mentioned below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend first renaming your existing myfile.csv to something else (like myfile_[DateOfLastRun].csv).  Then start fresh with a new myfile.csv.  That way if something goes wrong outside this process and you need whatever was in myfile.csv the day/week/month before, you have it.

You could use [BCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) for this in a BAT file:

```
set vardate=%DATE:~4,10%
set varDateWithoutSlashes=%vardate:/=-%
bcp "SELECT someColumns FROM aTable" queryout myFile_%varDateWithoutSlashes%.csv -t, -c -T
```

The example above creates your CSV with the date already in the name.  You could also rename the existing file, then create your new myfile.csv without the date:

```
set vardate=%DATE:~4,10%
set varDateWithoutSlashes=%vardate:/=-%
ren myFile.csv myFile_%varDateWithoutSlashes%.csv
bcp "SELECT someColumns FROM aTable" queryout myFile.csv -t, -c -T
```

Be sure to build in cleanup of old files somewhere - that can even be done in the same batch process as this one.

You can add DB name and server name to the bcp line - by default it connects to the local server and the user's default DB (See the [BCP documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) for even more options)

```
bcp databaseName "SELECT someColumns FROM aTable" queryout myFile.csv -t, -c -T -S serverName
```

Comment: But not just rename it.. keep X occurrences (30 days worth, 30 runs) of the file that way you don't keep putting new files out there without ever cleaning up.

Comment: Very true @xQbert - we build in cleanup steps as well and I forgot to mention that.  Thanks

Comment: @JenR Thanks for helping out! I understand your suggestion to have the file renamed for each run but I need the file to be overwritten and with the same name as I will have an FTP task in SSIS which will upload this file on an FTP Server on a daily basis.

Comment: Look at the second block of code in my example - it has your newest file with the same name always, and the older ones dated.  That way if your FTP breaks and you don't immediately notice (maybe you're on vacation), the missed files are still there and you can send them.

Comment: @JenR I gave your solution a shot but it is not working at a specific step.
I have created a bat file with the following codes:
cd:\Program Files\ Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn
set vardate=%DATE:~4,10%
set varDateWithoutSlashes=%vardate:/=-%
ren C:\myfile.csv myFile_%varDateWithoutSlashes%.csv
bcp "SELECT TOP 100 ReservationStayID,NameTitle,FirstName,LastName,ArrivalDate,DepartureDate FROM [GuestNameInfo]" queryout C:\myfile.csv -t, -c -T
I have then scheduled a task in Task Scheduler to run the task.

Comment: @JenR When the task is run, the file is renamed with the current date but no data is being exported into it. I guess I need to add the Server name in the codes but I am at a loss as to how to do it. Any pointers?

Comment: Did you look at the `BCP` documentation linked in the answer?  There are a number of other variables you can add to the bcp line that should help you.

Comment: I added the syntax for server name and DB name above

Comment: @JenR Thanks a lot!